# ¿Cómo creo una columna que sea condición de otras columnas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, server

```
create table BD_CAMPAÑAS_PA
(
PERIODO date not null,
PRODUCTO varchar(5) not null,
ID_CLIENTE varchar(8) not null,
PROMOCION varchar(20) not null,
OFERTA money not null,
BEHAVIOR real not null )

insert BD_CAMPAÑAS_PA 
values ('2017/01/01', 'CE', '10550908', '10K', 15000, 715)

insert BD_CAMPAÑAS_PA 
values ('2017/01/01', 'CD', '10550913', 'Tarifario', 14000, 680),
       ('2017/01/01', 'CE', '10550922', '0.99', 50000, 620),
       ('2017/01/01', 'CD', '80550939', 'Tarifario', 4500, 700),
       ('2017/01/01', 'CD', '10551013', 'Tarifario', 25000, 690),
       ('2017/01/01', 'CE', '10551044', '0.99', 45000, 680),
       ('2017/02/01', 'CE', '10550922', 'Tarifario', 15000, 640),
       ('2017/02/01', 'CD', '06758640', 'Tarifario', 50000, 710),
       ('2017/02/01', 'CE', '06759084', '4k', 4000, 700),
       ('2017/02/01', 'CD', '06759185', 'Tarifario', 35000, 690),
       ('2017/02/01', 'CE', '48485555', '0.99', 35000, 690)

select * from BD_CAMPAÑAS_PA

create table BD_VENTAS_CE
( PERIODO date not null,
ID_CLIENTE varchar(8) not null,
CANAL varchar(10) not null,
MONTO_RETIRO money not null,
PLAZO int not null,
TASA real not null) 

insert BD_VENTAS_CE
values ('2017/01/01', '10550922', 'TLMKT', 15000, 36, 3.35),
       ('2017/01/01', '10551044', 'TLMKT', 40000, 48, 0.99),
       ('2017/01/01', '10550908', 'BXI', 25000, 24, 2.5),
       ('2017/01/01', '47393978', 'CCFF', 50000, 48, 1.8),
       ('2017/02/01', '06759084', 'CCFF', 4000, 36, 2.5),
       ('2017/02/01', '12389551', 'TLMKT', 18000, 24, 2.6),
       ('2017/02/01', '08007721', 'CCFF', 45000, 48, 1.8)

select * FROM BD_VENTAS_CE

create table BD_VENTAS_CD
( PERIODO date not null,
ID_CLIENTE varchar(8) not null,
CANAL varchar(10) NOT NULL,
MONTO_RETIRO money not null,
PLAZO int not null,
TASA real not null)

insert BD_VENTAS_CD
values ('2017/01/01', '10550913', 'TLMKT', 14000, 48, 1.8),
       ('2017/01/01', '06759185', 'TLMKT', 30000, 36, 1.4),
       ('2017/01/01', '80550939', 'TLMKT', 12000, 48, 1.5),
       ('2017/02/01', '06758640', 'TLMKT', 30000, 36, 1.3),
       ('2017/02/01', '89436472', 'TLMKT', 25000, 36, 1.1)

Select * from BD_VENTAS_CD

create table BD_CARTERA
(ID_CLIENTE varchar(8) not null,
NOMBRE1 varchar(10) not null,
NOMBRECOMPLETO varchar(70) not null,
NROCUENTA varchar(5) not null,
SITUACION varchar(30) not null)

insert BD_CARTERA
values ('10550908', 'Luis', 'Luis Alberto Manrique Chang', '00005','Regular'),
       ('47895056', 'Robert', 'Robert Marzano Guerrero', '00007','Bloqueada'),
       ('10550922', 'Javier', 'Javier David Olivares', '00008','Cerrada'),
       ('08007721', 'Javier', 'Javier Villavicencio Quevedo', '00002','Regular'),
       ('10551044', 'Luis', 'Luis Aguilar Bartra', '00003','Regular'),
       ('44866823', 'Diana', 'Diana Granda Sánchez', '00001','Regular')
```

> Se sabe que para enviar un e-mail como publicidad  se necesita tener un
> Behavior de 690 o más y tener una oferta de no menos de S/ 20,000,
> mediante SQL agregar una columna a la tabla BD_CAMPAÑAS_PA que defina
> si al cliente se le enviará un e-mail o no en la campaña.

Lo que intentaba era esto:

```
select ID_CLIENTE,BEHAVIOR, OFERTA from BD_CAMPAÑAS_PA
where BEHAVIOR >= 690 and OFERTA >= 20000
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por pasos, primero tienes que añadir la columna a la tabla, para ello necesitas un `ALTER TABLE`, asi:

```
ALTER TABLE BD_CAMPAÑAS_PA ADD ENVIAR_MAIL INT;
```

Defini el campo `ENVIAR_MAIL` como `INT` asumiendo que si se enviara el correo valdrá 1 y si no 0.

Lo siguiente, en lo cual ya estabas más o menos encaminado (creo) es definir a quienes se les debe enviar el correo, eso no seria mediante un `SELECT` sino mediante un `UPDATE`, asi:

```
UPDATE BD_CAMPAÑAS_PA SET ENVIAR_MAIL = 1 WHERE BEHAVIOR >= 690 and OFERTA >= 20000;
```

Finalmente para ver los registros a los que se les enviará el correo, solamente hacemos un `SELECT`, asi:

```
SELECT * FROM BD_CAMPAÑAS_PA WHERE ENVIAR_MAIL = 1;
```

Te dejo el ejemplo:

<kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc43211437bf9201a17715e8a0bc82e5)</kbd>

Ojala sea lo que buscas. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me fue de ayuda, recién me estoy encaminando en SQL server.

Comment: @Delmis si la respuesta resolvio tu problema, puedes marcarla como aceptada. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma muy práctica, al menos a partir de **SQL Server 2014**, es usar [columnas calculadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2014), a menos que las definas como persistentes, son columnas "virtuales" que se recalculan en función de ciertas condiciones, en tu caso podrías crear la tabla así:

```
create table BD_CAMPAÑAS_PA
(
  PERIODO date not null,
  PRODUCTO varchar(5) not null,
  ID_CLIENTE varchar(8) not null,
  PROMOCION varchar(20) not null,
  OFERTA money not null,
  BEHAVIOR real not null,
  ENVIAR_MAIL AS (CASE WHEN BEHAVIOR >= 690 and OFERTA >= 20000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
);
```

`ENVIAR_MAIL` será la columna calculada en función de `CASE WHEN BEHAVIOR >= 690 and OFERTA >= 20000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. Lo interesante es que te desentiendes de la actualización cuando alguno de estos valores cambien.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, Patricio.